# Inserting html into jquery . smarty template

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty

All this code is inside a smarty template. 
Im trying to insert html code in jquery is there anyway to display my html code ?

So basically this code should get the resolution of the screen, and according to that resolution will display something in html(facebook comments)

```
{literal}
<script>
if ($(window).width() < 550) {
document.write("<div class="fb-comments" data-mobile="true" data-href="www.test.com"></div>");
}
else {
   something here
}

</script>
{/literal}
```

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: it wont display the html code inside the document.write() @ParkashKumar

Comment: Better to append this in any div, which is already present in your document.

Comment: tried this but didnt work:

'$("p").append('<div class="fb-comments" data-mobile="true" data-href="test"></div>');'

Comment: Downvoted, there is no smarty tag in this code.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is problem: Just escape the string

```
document.write('<div class="fb-comments" data-mobile="true" data-href="www.test.com"></div>');
```

You have used '"' inside "". So use single quote in write().

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it .

so what i did was playing around with the {literal} tag

```
document.write({/literal}'<div class="fb-comments" data-mobile="true" data-href="www.test.com"></div>'{literal});
```

Comment: You are still doing it wrong! It should be `document.write('{literal}<div class="fb-comments" data-mobile="true" data-href="www.test.com"></div>{/literal}');`

Comment: Nope, check well on my question i have already opened the literal tag once, I just closed that one and opened it again